# Windows Vista Aero blue lines around windows

Tags: windows, windows-vista, window, aero

I have Windows Vista Home Premium x64 installed on my PC with some registry tweaks for Aero.

I noticed that blue lines appeared on the right and bottom of the windows.

I turned off the transparency.

> GPU: NVIDIA 8400GS (342.01 Driver)

[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

What might be causing this?

Comment: Vista is out of support and shouldn't be used. That said, you're using the correct driver version and the problem may indicate the graphics can may fail but if it works fine without the "tweaks" then that's the problem and not the card.

Comment: I would remove those tweaks to see if the behavior still happens.  The fact you were able to capture this behavior with a screenshot, indicates this might not be a hardware issue, as hardware failures typically are difficult to capture with a screenshot.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'm using Aero on Home Premium with registry tweak because I cant enable Aero on this edition of vista

Comment: @Ramhound remove tweaks == disable aero

Comment: @Twikoffin - Yes; Exactly.  You should disable the feature in question which is enabled due to unsupported registry changes to verify the behavior you describe is caused (or not caused) by those changes.

Comment: @Ramhound it happens only with Aero. And also I have Windows 7 dual booted and I haven't got this problem

Comment: @Twikoffin - There are significant changes Vista and Windows 7.  Your issue due to the registry changes

Answer (score 0):

those blue outlines are actually normal, they're part of vista's aero. there's no weird tweaking shenanigans side effects going on.